# Anti-libertarian-ism in Chazal

Tags: halacha-theory, money, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, derabanan

Most of the halachos of Choshen Mishpat have to do with one person's responsibilities viz-a-viz another person's rights.  However, there is at least one halacha of which I am aware where Chazal told me what to do with my money for my own sake.

[Bava Metzia 47b](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3119&size=1):

> אמר ר' יוחנן דבר תורה מעות קונות ומפני מה אמרו משיכה קונה גזירה שמא יאמר לו נשרפו חטיך בעלייה סוף סוף מאן דשדא דליקה בעי שלומי אלא גזירה שמא תפול דליקה באונס אי מוקמת להו ברשותיה מסר נפשיה טרח ומציל ואי לא לא מסר נפשיה טרח ומציל

That is: On a Torah level, money creates a transaction.  However, the Sages established that the transaction does not happen until the point when the purchaser takes possession, lest there be a fire in the room where the seller has the merchandise, and the seller won't bother to save the merchandise that the purchaser now owns .

The person cannot say, "it's my money and I am willing to take the risk" in order to become the owner through paying for it. (See Shach C.M. 198:9-10)

Are there any other examples where Chazal made decrees for a person's own benefit, and can this be extrapolated to a generalization (i.e. that we should not assist someone, or perhaps even hinder someone, in doing something that we deem to be financially self-destructive)?

Comment: A person is not allowed to let another Jew charge him interest

Comment: @ClintEastwood That is because of a prohibition of Ribbis, not because of protecting your personal interests.

Comment: Decrees for a person's own benefit ? perhaps maaser kesafim applies where our sages do not allow you to give more than 1/5 so you yourself don't become poor. (not sure if this is universally agreed upon. could be a billionaire could give more. no time for sources today) extrapolation ? proceed with extreme caution as each case would need to be examined individually.

Comment: How do you define financially self-destructive @YEZ? Is giving 1/5 of someone's money not financially self-destructive?

Comment: @gaagu was that directed at me?

Comment: @gaagu I was more referring to bad investments.  I think giving away money is a bad example for 2 reasons - 1 even if it isn't encouraged, it takes effect (i.e. chazal do not undo such a transaction). 2 - That is not a "bad choice" the person is making, i.e. he knows if he gives away money that he won't have it anymore and isn't getting anything (in this world) in return.  Someone investing in quack-medicine would be a good example in my mind.

Comment: כל ממון של חבירו שאדם יכול להציל שלא יאבד חייב להציל והוא בכלל השבת אבידה -Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 187:1

Answer (score -1):

**Kitzur Shulchan Aruch - Hilchot Aveidah Umetziah (187:1)**

> כל ממון של חבירו שאדם יכול להציל שלא יאבד חייב להציל והוא בכלל השבת אבידה
>
> A friend's money that a person can save from being lost, they must save, and it's considered 'returning a lost object'.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't answer "Are there any other examples where Chazal made decrees for a person's own benefit", but it answers "can this be extrapolated to a generalization (i.e. that we should not assist someone, or perhaps even hinder someone, in doing something that we deem to be financially self-destructive)", by demonstrating that Rabbi Ganzfried considers saving another's money part of the Mitzvah of Hashavat Aveida.

Comment: How do you know that applies if the owner of the money would rather it not be saved?

Comment: I don't. How did I imply that I did?

Comment: Then I don't see how it addresses self-destructiveness?

Comment: If you meant to ask about when someone says I don't think the way I am investing my money is self-destructive, then what Rabbi Ganzfried says seems to apply, as the decision is going to cause him/her to lose money. How else do you understand it?

Comment: The Kitzur is talking about, for example, saving his property from a fire or a flood.  Not about stopping him from making bad investments (unless you have some indication otherwise, this is no better than quoting the chazal about לא תעמד על דם רעך)

Comment: How do you know it isn't talking about stopping bad expenditure with no chance of benefitting?! Indeed, it seems similar to saving a field from ruination before the fact! If I had quoted לא תעמוד על דם רעך would you have been satisfied? What do you mean by "it's no better than"? Aren't you looking for sources? (But in truth, לא תעמוד על דם רעך is talking about life threatening situations. It's השבת אבידה.) What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry you didn't ping me, I didn't see this until just now.  What's wrong is that my whole question is with the knowledge that there is such a thing as לא תעמד על דם רעך which is applied to saving other's property by Chazal, and I am wondering if this applies in the face of the owner making conscious decisions.  There is a qualitative difference between saving him from damage that he himself would save himself from and stopping him from consciously doing what he thinks is beneficial. You haven't addressed that point.

Comment: @YEZ What is the source in Chazal that לא תעמוד על דם רעך applies to saving property?

Comment: Granted in my opinion it has to be absolute in your mind that the other will lose, but if it's a mitzvah (and you are helping them, why does it matter if the other person may feel slighted or whatever consideration you are using?!

Comment: @gaagu My question is if it's a mitzvah.  You haven't shown that yet.

Comment: @YEZ Consider theoretically that it was a mitzvah. Then a person's personal considerations would be irrelevant, because it's a mitzvah. Since the terminology used by Rabbi Ganzfried is general, there is no reason for me to rule out a theoretical possibility that has no logical resistance to it.

Comment: Maybe this quote seems ironic in the case of השבת אבידה, but מצות לאו ליהנות ניתנו.